# Why does `transferAll` leave an existential deposit despite keep alive flag set to false?

Tags: frame

I recently had to transfer all the funds of an account `A` to an account `B`. To do so, I used extrinsic `balances.transferAll(B, false)` where the second argument is the `keepAlive` flag (see [documentation](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/polkadot-v1.8.0/substrate/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L620-L634)) and signed with the key of `A`.

After a successful extrinsic submission, the account `A` still exists with an existential deposit (see screenshot below).

[image]

I was expecting that with no keep alive, the account's balances would just reach 0.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Some pallet seems to depent on that account to be alive, since it has a `consumer` ref. Is it maybe used as Proxy etc? Otherwise please post the on-chain address. Can also do this privately for investigation purpose only `oliver.tale-yazdi@parity.io`.

Comment: No proxy here. What we did is transfer some tokens with vesting (`vesting.vestedTransfer(...)`) to `A`, then cancel the vesting (`vesting.forceRemoveVestingSchedule(...)`) and transfer funds back to `B`. I sent an e-mail with real data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the currency module on how it handled consumer references.
These references can keep an account alive to ensure that other pallets that depend on it dont suddenly break since the account disappeared.

In your case the issue came the vested transfer. The `vestedTransfer` created two consumer references for the account instead of one. Then the `forceRemoveVestingSchedule` only removed one of those references instead of both. Now the account cannot be reaped anymore.

It was fixed in [#1976](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1976), but all chains who ran into the issue prior to this will have a messed up storage. We are working on fixing this, but currently the scope of the issue is still unclear.